# How to set Ignore_unmapped true in elasticsearch sort by distance in java?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I want to get sort by distance response from elastic search but I have unmapped longitude and latitude values in elastic search hence I am not getting any result using below query.

How can i get `"ignore_unmapped":"true"` in sort like below query

I have tried using GeoDistanceSortBuilder and there is no method to set ignore_unmapped. I cannot find any other class to build sort query

```
{
geoSort = geoDistanceSort(LOCATION_POINT_HOLDER, 0, 0).unit(DistanceUnit.KILOMETERS).order(SortOrder.DESC);
}
```

> "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
>   "reason": "failed to find mapper for [location] for geo distance based sort"

I am getting this error without setting ignore_unmapped:true.

Answer (score 0):

**repalce elasticsearch maven dependency earlier than 6.3.2**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>6.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
    <version>6.3.0</version>
    <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

**or upgrade the version of elasticsearch**

Answer (score 0):

In 7.2.0 you can set it through unmapped e.g

```
SortBuilders
 .geoDistanceSort("location", 0.0, 0.0)
 .ignoreUnmapped()
```